# PHP - Unknown: failed to open stream

Tags: php, wamp, localhost

Bom, criei um programa básico que retorna duas variáveis em *PHP*, porém estou tendo alguns erros ao tentar 'rodar' o programa pelo *WampServer*.

Como estou utilizando o *WampServer*, criei uma pasta chamada `curso` dentro da pasta `www`. Até aqui tudo bem, atualizo o *localhost* e meu projeto é exibido! Assim que entro no meu projeto, é exibido o arquivo que contém o meu código (que retorna duas variáveis), porém quando abro este arquivo, estou tendo alguns erros:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp64/www/curso/#02 - Variáveis.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

O código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Variáveis</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $txt = "Olá, mundo!";
        $num = 14;
        echo $txt;
        echo $num;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver este erro?

Comment: experimente tirar o acento do nome dá pagina... está variáveis.php coloque sem acento, o uso de acento nesse tipo de coisa é uma má pratica

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Obrigado!

Comment: Coloque como resposta @AndersonHenrique para fechar o topico

Answer (score -1, accepted):

experimente tirar o acento do nome dá pagina... está variáveis.php coloque sem acento, o uso de acento nesse tipo de coisa é uma má pratica

Comment: Explique melhor a sua resposta, como por exemplo, como da as permissões.

Comment: @WictorChaves Ja foi solucionado... Só coloquei pra fechar o tópico e acredito que esteja bem claro, ele colocou o nome de váriaveis.php com acento e só falei pra tirar, simples não tem oque detalhar mais daqui